# Radar system for micro meter accuracy

Tags: radar

I need a radar system to sense a movable object within [0..150 meter] range. The desired accuracy is around 100 micron. However, at far distance 1 mm could be fine.

As far as I read, 3D Lidar systems can not achieve this level of accuracy (correct me if I am wrong please).

Stereo camera systems can achieve this level of accuracy theoretically. However, designing such system is not practical at all due to the high focal length and baseline needed.

What are other possible options that are practical for the desired working range and accuracy?

**Edit (More information):**

- The object moves relatively slow (less than 1 meter/sec, most of the time few centimeters per second)
- The object size is around 30*30*30 cm^3. However, the reference point of the object can be added. For example, in the Stereo Vision suggested solution I was about to add a very small red led. So, the reference point can be customized for the application.
- The object can rotate around itself.

Comment: 100 *micron* accuracy? That's going to require some expensive optics experts.

Comment: I'm curious as to what kind of phase noise performance you would need in order to achieve this. How fast is your "thing" moving (ie, how much time do you have to integrate over?)

Comment: At that kind of accuracy it is critical to know the reference points for the distance measurement. How large is your object? What point of the object is the range to be measured?.. Can the object rotate as it moves? Where on the measurement system is your reference point? and how stable is it? You are asking for 1 ppm accuracy. Can you provide more information as to your application so that we can provide a more relevant answer.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have edited the question with more hopefully helpful information.

Comment: If you can get do this its already been done, and its going to be expensive.

Comment: This isn't going to be easy.  Using conventional time-of-flight, a difference of 100µm represents a difference in return time of about 0.66 picoseconds if my maths is right.  You can detect phase difference in the returned signal for fine measurement, but that doesn't help until you have a coarse measurement.

Comment: Hewlett Packard made fringe-line-counters for milling-machines. You need a similar approach.